# problem with text color in Visual studio + VisualGDB

Tags: visual-studio, editor, visual-studio-2019, visualgdb

each time I open a visualGDB(5.4 r8) embedded project in visual studio 2019, the text color changes like the image below.

[image]

- this problem only exists for VisualGDB projects
- this problem didn't exist earlier for VisualGDB on Visual studio 2017
- I can fix it each time by changing the visual studio default color theme. (e.g. switch from dark to light). but only for that session. after I close and reopen the VisualGDB projects I have to do it again.
- I have cleaned VisualGDB cache with no luck.
- I have set the font properties in options to default with no luck.
- there should be some problem with intellisense cuz when i change the settings, the text gets back to normal for a few seconds.

any suggestions to how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a known issue caused by a recent change in the internal color encoding of Visual Studio 2019.

We have already fixed it in the VisualGDB 5.4 branch (simply re-downloading the installer from http://visualgdb.com/download/ should resolve the problem) and will include the fix in VisualGDB 5.5 Preview 1 that will be released next week.

In case the incorrect settings get cached somewhere, please use Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors->Text Editor->C/C++ <...> to reset the background color of the affected items to the default value.